# Possible to Add a Lookup Relationship to Network Object?

Tags: custom-field, lookup, master-detail

I am looking to add a custom field that is of type "Lookup" or "Master-Detail" to the [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_network.htm) object.  This appears to be missing from the list of objects that can be selected.

[image: choose related object]

Is it possible to do this?  If not, what is the best way to get around the limitation?  Perhaps, adding a text field that contains the NetworkId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your use case, but I have traditionally gone with the solution you outlined - a text field that has NetworkId coupled with some `before update, before insert` and `after delete` triggers to make sure the id is valid.  The other option is to see if Network can relate back to your custom object (or if you need a to-many, to a join custom object)

Comment: Going with this answer since I don't think it is possible today.  Thanks!